# Azure Function App Container Failing to Start at Minikube Container Error: The listener for function 'EventHubCSharpFunc' was unable to start

Tags: azure, kubernetes, minikube

I created a very simple Azure functionApp using visual Studio Code which does nothing fancy but logs the received message(Function App listen to Eventhub message in Azure). This works and get hosted well when i debug the function app locally. However, when I publish this into minikube as container, it throws below error:

```
The listener for function 'EventHubCSharpFunc' was unable to start.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException: The listener for function 'EventHubCSharpFunc' was unable to start. ---> Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.EventProcessorConfigurationException: Encountered error while fetching the list of EventHub PartitionIds ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpEventHubClient.CreateConnectionAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.CreateValue(TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.Management.AmqpServiceClient.OpenRequestResponseLinkAsync(String type, String address, Nullable`1 entityType, String[] requiredClaims, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.Management.AmqpServiceClient.OpenLinkAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.CreateValue(TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.Management.AmqpServiceClient.GetRuntimeInformationAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpEventHubClient.OnGetRuntimeInformationAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventHubClient.GetRuntimeInformationAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.PartitionManager.GetPartitionIdsAsync()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.PartitionManager.GetPartitionIdsAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.PartitionManager.GetPartitionIdsAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.PartitionManager.InitializeStoresAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.PartitionManager.StartAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.EventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorFactoryAsync(IEventProcessorFactory factory, EventProcessorOptions processorOptions)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs.EventHubListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs\Listeners\EventHubListener.cs:line 46
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean allowRetry) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\FunctionListener.cs:line 68
```

I tried to check if my cluster is having internet access, but I am successfully able to ping internet IP from other containers in minikube.

```
public static class EventHubCSharpFunc
    {
        [FunctionName("EventHubCSharpFunc")]
        public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("containertestevthub", Connection = "EventGridPerfEventHun_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
        {
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

            foreach (EventData eventData in events)
            {
                try
                {
                    string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);

                    // Replace these two lines with your processing logic.
                    log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {messageBody}");
                    await Task.Yield();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
                    // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
                    exceptions.Add(e);
                }
            }

            // Once processing of the batch is complete, if any messages in the batch failed processing throw an exception so that there is a record of the failure.

            if (exceptions.Count > 1)
                throw new AggregateException(exceptions);

            if (exceptions.Count == 1)
                throw exceptions.Single();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I hosted container image at dockerhub  -  harkiratiiit/azurefunceventhub

Answer (score 0):

looking into "**EventHubCSharpFunc was unable to start**" and "**Resource temporarily unavailable**", please try to connect from *Your APP POD* to *Eventhub*.

Please verify if your connection and credentials are working inside *Your APP POD*.
You can find more about **how to pass credentials as Secrets** into your POD or **Create a Secret based on existing Docker credentials** [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).

For troubleshooting purposes please use those below commands to get more information from your cluster:

```
kubectl log <your_pod_with_application>
kubectl describe <your_pod_with_application>
kubectl get events
kubectl get all --all-namespaces
```